"overflows indirect symbol table" when compiling polkadot
Only happens when compiling the polkadot-sdk/polkadot with release profile using my macbook...
Simplly cd polkadot-sdk/polkadot and cargo build --release, using latest rustc stable (1.83.0), gives the error at the beginning:
Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/private/tmp/polkadot-sdk/target/release/build/typenum-9817518158da15e8/build-script-main` (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill)
error: failed to run custom build command for `thiserror v1.0.61`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/private/tmp/polkadot-sdk/target/release/build/thiserror-560f6ba163f232d6/build-script-build` (signal: 6, SIGABRT: process abort signal)
  --- stderr
  dyld[83598]: section __got overflows indirect symbol table
error: failed to run custom build command for `libc v0.2.155`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/private/tmp/polkadot-sdk/target/release/build/libc-f9ed4a7333520dc2/build-script-build` (signal: 6, SIGABRT: process abort signal)
  --- stderr
  dyld[83613]: section __got overflows indirect symbol table
error: failed to run custom build command for `libc v0.2.155`

This is the macbook info:
# uname -a
Darwin mac 23.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 23.6.0: Mon Jul 29 21:13:00 PDT 2024; root:xnu-10063.141.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Processor 2,3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9
Memory 16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
macOS 14.6.1 (23G93)

But my colleague that has the same mac but with 32GB memory doesn't have problems.
I know it's not a bug of code, but is there any way to mitigate this?
